# boost split string

Tags: c++, boost

How can you split without making copies of string?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::regex` as defined in C++0x or in C++98 TR1 - this returns iterators into the string (well, behind a facade anyhow) - so it doesn't involve copying the string.  The C++0x regex variant supports both extracting matches and splitting (extracting *non-matches*) - so it's a full replacement for `strtok` with lots of additional power.

See [John Cook's webpage](http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_regex.html#retrieve) for example, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Regular_expressions) or a [video by Stephan T Lavavej](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-8-of-n).  You may need to use [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/index.html) until C++0x is more widely implemented; the two are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Using Boost Split, you can't. The obvious (but ugly) way to split strings without copying them would be `strtok` (or, preferably, `strtok_s`).

Comment: I thought you could do with iterator_range type using boost.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Do you know why Boost split takes a reference and not a const reference for the `Input` argument? I would assume that the split function would never change the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recipient akin to `llvm::StringRef`, which is merely a pointer into a `char` array and a size, and provides no mutator to the underlying sequence.

However that would mean recoding the split logic on yourself.